# How to run a video file in jquery-terminal

Tags: javascript, jquery-terminal

I am trying to create a website based on the initial graphics of jquery.terminal and I have noticed that there are currently no questions related to video management.
I got to see questions related to images, such as this one [Creating a Linux terminal themed website using HTML and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656996/creating-a-linux-terminal-themed-website-using-html-and-javascript/64657034) but if I try to use the same writing style in the end I load a blank space.

```
mpv: function(file) {
    this.echo($('<video src="assets/video/video.mp4">'));
}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see you use normal HTML, so the question is [how to use video in HTML](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-insert-video-in-web-page-and-play-it-using-html/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid syntax for video in HTML.

The syntax is as follow:

```html
<video width="500px" height="500px"
    controls="controls">
     
    <source src="vid.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

video tag doesn't accept src attribute only source tags inside.

so you need to use this:

```js
this.echo($('<video><source src="assets/video/video.mp4"/></video>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the extra "file" parameter in your function.
It should be:

```
mpv: function () {
this.echo($('<video src="assets/video/video.mp4"></video>'));
}
```